# Undefined index: Laravel & TMDB api

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, api

If I enter the wrong url address for example http://127.0.0.1:8000/okec

> Undefined index: poster_path

and not 404 not found

```
<div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
            <div class="figure">
                @if ($infoFilm['poster_path'])
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail rounded" src="{{ 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/'.$infoFilm['poster_path'] }}" alt="Poster">
                @else
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail rounded" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x240?text=mUaacH" alt="NoImage">
                @endif 
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller

```
public function details($id) {

    $infoFilm = Http::withToken(config('services.tmdb.token')) 
    -> get(config('services.tmdb.apiurl').'movie/'.$id) 
    -> json();

    return view('pages.users.details', [
        'infoFilm' => $infoFilm,
    ]);
```

Route

```
Route::get('{details}', [FilmController::class, 'details'])->name('details');
```

is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: For the movie you're looking up, `$infoFilm['poster_path']` apparently isn't set. Check the JSON to double-check it's named what you think it is; chances are some films don't *have* a poster.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED :

```
@empty( $infoFilm['id'] )
    @php
        abort(404);
    @endphp
@endempty
```